# Use variables in azure stream analytics properties

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I want to reduce the number of overrides during the deployment of my ASA by using environment variables in my properties.

### Expectations

Having variables defined in the `asaproj.json` or the `JobConfig.json` file or a `.env` file.

```json
{
  ...
  "variables": [
    "environment": "dev"
  ]
}
```

Call those variables in a properties file such as an SQL Reference properties input file

```json
{
    "Name": "sql-query",
    "Type": "Reference data",
    "DataSourceType": "SQL Database",
    "SqlReferenceProperties": {
        "Database": "${environment}-sql-bdd",
        "Server": "${environment}-sql",
        "User": "user",
        "Password": null,
        "FullSnapshotPath": "sql-query.snapshot.sql",
        "RefreshType": "Execute periodically",
        "RefreshRate": "06:00:00",
        "DeltaSnapshotPath": null
    },
    "DataSourceCredentialDomain": null,
    "ScriptType": "Input"
}
```

### Attempt

I could use a powershell script to override values from the ARM variables file generated by the npm package `azure-streamanalytics-cicd`. It's not clean at all.

### Problem

I can't find resources about environment variables in azure stream analytics online. Does such a thing exist ? If so, can you provide some piece of documentation ?